# Objective-C / JSON, Array of dictionaries, parsing array nested in dictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, nsarray, nested

The JSON that I am parsing can be found here 'redacted'.

I can correctly grab all of the objects from this JSON except notifications and devices.
I am having a lot of trouble being able to get the array of device dictionaries containing 'deviceId's. My code right now looks like this

```
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                    iViuListOfCustomersURL];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                          withObject:data waitUntilDone:NO];
});




- (void) fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json;
    json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData // 1

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error]; 

    NSArray* customers = json; 


    for(int i = 0; i < customers.count ; i++){
        NSDictionary *customer = [customers objectAtIndex:i];
        cmsServer = [customer objectForKey:@"cmsServer"]; 
        iconUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[customer objectForKey:@"iconUrl"]];
        wideLogo = [customer objectForKey:@"wideLogo"]; 
        customerNo = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[customer objectForKey:@"customerNo"] intValue]];
        placeName = [customer objectForKey:@"placeName"];
        distance = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[customer objectForKey:@"distance"] floatValue]];
        placeId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[customer objectForKey:@"placeId"] intValue]];
        address = [customer objectForKey:@"address"];
        cmsName = [customer objectForKey:@"cmsName"]; 
        hasLocations = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[customer objectForKey:@"hasLocations"]intValue]];
        isFavorite = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[customer objectForKey:@"isFavorite"] intValue]];
        longitude = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[customer objectForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue]];
        latitude = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[customer objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue]];
        hasArtifacts = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[customer objectForKey:@"hasArtifacts"]intValue]];

        // I have tried a number of things and this was what I had for the last try.
        devices = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[customer objectForKey:@"devices"]];
        NSLog(@"%@",devices.count);
    }
```

}

I am relatively new to objective-c and wanted to figure this out on my own but I have spent too much time on this issue and I cannot continue without these device IDs.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it will make a difference but have you tried:

```
devices = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[customer objectForKey:@"devices"]];
```

The other thing you can try is going through the elements in it and adding them one by one into devices:

```
for(DeviceObject *deviceObject in [customer objectForKey:@"devices"])
{
  [devices addObject:deviceObject];
}
```

The other thing you can look into is the empty values you pass sometimes in your json.